# Can't open .ods file I created and saved in Google drive - no application for "application/x-vnd.oasis opendocument.spreadsheet type" files

Tags: libreoffice

I created a spreadsheet in LibreOffice calc and saved it remotely, Google, as a .ods file. When I double clicked this file in files to open it I got:

There is no application for "application/x-vnd.oasis opendocument.spreadsheet type" files

and could not open the file, however I could open it from File > Recent Documents in an open blank LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet!

How can I make this file open from a double click in files?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the file, select "Properties" in the menu that appears. Select the "Open with" tab, look for LibreOffice Calc in the application list and select it. Click "Set as default" to have this file type open by default in Calc.